# ¿Se puede calcular el tamaño de un div respecto a otro div con calc()?

Tags: html, css, div, design, width

Buen día.

Estoy maquetando una sección de un página web y me preguntaba si se puede definir el ancho de un div respecto a otro que es responsivo con la función "calc()". Por ejemplo:

```css
/* El ancho de este div debería de cambiar respecto al ancho determinado en la tabla*/
.a_modificar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* El ancho de la tabla se mantiene */
.tabla {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1; 
    background: green;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="a_modificar">
            El ancho de este div debe cambiar respecto al ancho de la tabla
        </div>


        <div class="tabla">
               
            <div class="box">1</div>
            <div class="box">2</div>
            <div class="box">3</div>
            <div class="box">4</div>
            <div class="box">5</div>
            <div class="box">6</div>
            <div class="box">7</div>
            <div class="box">8</div>
            <div class="box">9</div>
            <div class="box">10</div>
            <div class="box">11</div>
            <div class="box">12</div>
            <div class="box">13</div>
            <div class="box">14</div>
            <div class="box">15</div>
            <div class="box">16</div>

        </div>
        
        <a>El ancho de la tabla se mantiene igual</a>
```

O sea, que lo que quiero saber, es si con CSS puedo usar la propiedad y función "width: calc()", para que acorde con el ancho de la tabla, el div "a_modificar" cambie únicamente su ancho.

Tengo entendido que sería relativamente "fácil" si establezco medidas iguales para ambos, pero si el tablero cambia de tamaño, ¿sería posible con CSS?

Gracias por su atención.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Si es relativo a su padre si se puede usando porcentajes, ya que por ejemplo, cuando pones width:10%, se refiere a un 10% del ancho del padre. Tu estas ocupando vh el cual es relativo al viewport (que vendría siendo lo que se ve en pantalla) y eso no te sirve

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, muy buena explicación, saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

con las variables css es muy simple, proba algo asi:

```
*{
  --ancho: 60px
}

.div-uno{
  height: 50px;
  width: var(--ancho);
}
.div-dos{
  width:calc( var(--ancho)/2);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente :D